# SliverFillRemaining with a SizeTransition occupies more space than the viewport

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

I have a problem with a `SizeTransition` that is within a `SliverFillRemaining`. The issue is that the `SliverFillRemaining` does not adjust its size proportionally to the height of the `SizeTransition`. Even when the sizeFactor of the `SizeTransition` is 0, the `SliverFillRemaining` still occupies the space it would when the `SizeTransition`'s sizeFactor is 1. I expected `SliverFillRemaining` to only fill the remaining space in the viewport but in the sample code below it uses more space than necessary. This is not an issue with `SingleChildScrollView` for which I've provided sample code as well.

[image: Image showing error]

Code with SliverFillRemaining showing too much space being taken up:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: const CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizeTransitionExample(),
                  SizeTransitionExample(),
                  SizeTransitionExample(),
                  SafeArea(child: Text("Text")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SizeTransitionExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SizeTransitionExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<SizeTransitionExample> createState() => _SizeTransitionExampleState();
}

class _SizeTransitionExampleState extends State<SizeTransitionExample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat(reverse: true);
  late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageHeight = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;

    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: _animation,
      child: Center(
        child: FlutterLogo(size: pageHeight / 3),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code with SingleChildScrollView with the expected behavior:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: const SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ColoredBox(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizeTransitionExample(),
                SizeTransitionExample(),
                SizeTransitionExample(),
                SafeArea(child: Text("Text")),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SizeTransitionExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SizeTransitionExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<SizeTransitionExample> createState() => _SizeTransitionExampleState();
}

class _SizeTransitionExampleState extends State<SizeTransitionExample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat(reverse: true);
  late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageHeight = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;

    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: _animation,
      child: Center(
        child: FlutterLogo(size: pageHeight / 3),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```